# delete from salesforce a record by ID and integrate with SSIS

Tags: ssis, salesforce, dbamp

can anyone tell me how I can delete record from salesforce with dbamp and integrate that in SSIS ?

Comment: There are 2 extensions in the Visual Studio Gallery, did you check them out? 1. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/efecda8e-4853-415c-ad69-f3c81eaba7fa?SRC=VSIDE 2. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63c905f4-9e90-42d0-87c9-9162f5cb8a3c?SRC=VSIDE

Comment: hm ... no do you have some sample examples ?

Comment: No, I do not have any experience with those 2 extensions. We are using MS Dynamics CRM, and there are similar SSIS-extensions, which work quite nice (better than the standard-SSIS-stuff). That's why I proposed those extensions to you. There are testversions for both, you check them out.